# I have moved a zipped file to a directory which does not exist

Tags: zip, mv

I have moved a zipped file to a directory which does not exist. It resulted in creating a new file. But I am not able to open/unzip it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably ran something like

```
mv foo.zip bar
```

If there was no directory called `bar`, you have now renamed your `foo.zip` to `bar`. However, `unzip` expects a `.zip` extension. So, all you need to do is rename it again:

```
mv bar bar.zip
```

Now you should be able to unzip as expected.

---

Next time, please include the exact command you ran and the errors you got in your question, it makes it much easier to understand the problem.